# Fewest number of changes to an imperfect melody to make it perfect

Tags: python

I have just started learning how to code 'competitively' in competitions and came across this problem:

A 'perfect' melody is one that has the same 3 numbers repeating over, for example:
123123123
And so a 'non-perfect' one would be for example: 123122121

Now the question asks how many numbers need to be changed in an imperfect melody to make it 'perfect'. Below is an example: (in the first row of the input file , the first one is the amount of notes and the second one is the max value each note can take and then the rest of the numbers are the notes in order)

Example:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TzZ4.png)

I have produced a solution that doesn't solve most of the test cases and I don't see why. My code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000000)




# N is the number of notes.
N = None

# K is the largest number which could be a note.
K = None

# S contains the sequence of notes forming the song.
S = [None for x in range(100005)]

answer = None

# Open the input and output files.
input_file = open("melodyin.txt", "r")
output_file = open("melodyout.txt", "w")

# Read the value of N and K.
input_line = input_file.readline().strip()
N, K = map(int, input_line.split())

# Read each note in the song.
for i in range(0, N):
    S[i] = int(input_file.readline().strip())


notes_list = []
for i in range(0, N):
    notes_list.append(S[i])


count = 0
sep = []
for i in range(N//3):
    sep.append([notes_list[count], notes_list[count+1], notes_list[count+2]])
    count += 3

errors = 0
for i in range(len(sep)-1):
    if sep[0][0] != sep[i+1][0]:
        errors += 1
    if sep[0][1] != sep[i+1][1]:
        errors += 1
    if sep[0][2] != sep[i+1][2]:
        errors += 1
    else:
        pass
# Write the answer to the output file.
output_file.write("%d\n" % (errors))

# Finally, close the input/output files.
input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

additionally these are the constraints:
• 3≤N≤99999.
• N is a multiple of three. • 1≤K≤100000.
• 1≤Si ≤K,for all i

Comment: You implicitely supposed that the first sequence of 3 is the "right" one and that all others must be changed to this one...

Comment: _doesn't solve most of the test cases_ When a test case fails, does it tell you any details?  Or just "fail" with no other explanation?

Comment: no, it just says fail as it doesn't want to reveal the test cases @JohnGordon

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, how would I know which one is the 'correct' one then?

Comment: What is the point of `sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000000)` in code that doesn't use *any* recursion?

Comment: I imagine most of the work will be in _deciding_ what the correct sequence should be!  Once you know that, the rest is simple.

Comment: @DavidCsontos if this is from CodinGame, there is a way to see the inputs for a test case, just `print()` to `stderr`, like this `print('whatever', file=sys.stderr)`

Comment: They're looking for fewest changes .  i.e. `129123123` would be most efficiently changed to 123123123  (n=1) not 129129129 (n=2)